# Display a plotted line without having to wait for a new ticker update

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a script that uses the `timeframe="D"` argument. Because of this, on weekly and monthly charts, it does not plot the data right away, but only with the first ticker update.

To visualize what I am referring to, you can run the script below on a **monthly chart**. If the exchange is open at the time, you will see it takes a few seconds until data is displayed (it is important to load a new symbol every time). The moment the data gets plotted is the moment a new ticker update takes place for that symbol. If the exchange is closed, then the data will not be shown at all. For testing purposes, you can still try crypto symbols, as they trade 24h/day.

Is there any way to enforce the script to plot the line without having to wait for a new ticker update? I am trying to make it load faster and work all the time (not only when the market is open and ticking).

I need to mention that the `timeframe="D"` argument needs to stay in place. I get my signals from the daily timeframe, but I always check monthly charts. Replacing it with `request.security_lower_tf` is also not an option, for multiple reasons.

I use the script to plot a signal line at the last bar using 64 `plot` instructions (maximum allowed). So, keeping this structure intact (last bar + multiple plots) is also a key requirement - there is no room for change there.

Thank you!

```
//@version=5
indicator("", timeframe="D")

var int n = na

if (barstate.islast)
    n := 1

plot(n, color=#000000, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-4)
plot(n, color=#000000, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-3)
plot(n, color=#000000, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-2)
plot(n, color=#000000, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-1)
plot(n, color=#000000, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pinescript assumes that the first ticker update may result in a new bar. So it waits for it and marks the latest bar as penultimate bar. You can change your if condition to check for penultimate or later bar and it should work.

```
if (bar_index>=last_bar_index-1) 
    n := 1
```

When the first ticker update happens then you can track the same and bypass this condition too so that it will work normally after that

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed the 'barstate.islast' condition with yours, but nothing has changed. It does not work if the exchange is closed, I just tried it on some asian stock symbols. It is working now for US stocks, but as soon as the market closes, the plot will no longer show on monthly charts.

Comment: If the market is closed then it assumes two bars are missing, you can change it to if (bar_index>=last_bar_index-2)

Comment: Still not working. I also tried some of the 'barstate' built-in variables, without any success.